# UE5 Create Event issues

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I am having issues creating an event inside a function.
My function calls a “Bind Event to On Destroyed”. When dragging out the Event node, I call Create Event. After dragging the output of my bind event actor into the Create Event “Object” input, I select “Create a matching event” from the dropdown.

Afterwards, a new custom event appears inside my function, let’s call it “RespawnEvent”:
[image: RespawnEvent]

Now, when I search for the event in my “Create Event” dropdown, it just doesn’t appear:

[image: Create Event]

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might be wrong on this but I think you can only create events in the main graph and not in functions.

Comment: @DeimosPhx yep, that was the solution on it. I was a bit confused since UE5 allowed creating events that were showing up inside the function but didn't work.